# Color formatting line charts on tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a line chart that is colored by a calculated field, it is written that if the previous 2 markers had increased, then color it blue, else color it red.. I have it set up  and it is correct except that tableau starts the change of the color of the line chart halfway in between markers. For example, on a market that fulfills my requirements, the line before the marker will be half red and then turn blue as it gets closer to the mark. Then after the mark it will be blue and then turn red halfway to the next mark.

I need it to be completely blue from when the line increases and completely red when the line decreases.

Thank you in advance for all the help and let me know if I need to include anything!

Comment: Some sample data would be great :)   I'm trying to guess what your graph looks like now and I think the field on Color might be a green coloured field (meaning continuous) which would make this problem happen.  If you convert the field to discrete (blue coloured field) then it might work the way you're after.  This is only a guess though, if it doesn't work please supply more details (hopefully some sample data - just a single CSV row that shows the problem)

Comment: I tried to convert it to discrete but that didn’t work sadly. For example data it is very basic. Months of the year and then profit for those months. I want to show the chart lines a green color when there are 3 or more months increases in a row.

Comment: can you add the image unable to understand

Comment: Or post your workbook to Tableau Public so we can see what you're trying to do